# Spring integration move file after processing

Tags: spring-integration, polling

How to move a file after processing in spring integration after processing file ..?
I have followed  http://xpadro.blogspot.com/2016/07/spring-integration-polling-file.html  to implement the file polling , but I need to add onSuccess and OnError transnational events (with out XML configurations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "transaction", file systems are generally not transactional, but you can add an advice to the final consumer in the flow...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So40625031Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So40625031Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                    Files.inboundAdapter(new File("/tmp/foo")), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                .handle("processor", "process", e -> e.advice(advice()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public Processor processor() {
        return new Processor();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice advice() {
        return new AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
                File file = message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class);
                try {
                    Object result = callback.execute();
                    file.renameTo(new File("/tmp/bar", file.getName()));
                    System.out.println("File renamed after success");
                    return result;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    file.renameTo(new File("/tmp/baz", file.getName()));
                    System.out.println("File renamed after failure");
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static class Processor {

        public void process(String in) {
            System.out.println(in);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This exactly what I am looking for . Thank you for the solution.

Comment: It didn't work when I replaced `Transformers.fileToString()` with `Transformers.fromJson(My.class)` in order to read directly a JSON object from a file. The JSON transformer lost the file name header. Added `.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, "payload"))` just after `from(Files...)` to make it work.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks